# conda executable not found in pycharm and running the add interpreter all the time

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I want to use my conda environment in pycharm. But there was no option at all:enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX4YF.png)

I choose the path about Anaconda\Scripts\conda.exe or Anaconda\condabin\conda.bat ,and i choose the following options:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOVo7.png)
After click ok, I've been stuck in this window:enter image description here:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0lzN.png)
maybe I have not downloaded something.
Another question is when I create a new project by conda: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DServ.png), after click ok, it also have been stuck in this window:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kThBJ.png)
Is there something I didn't pack? Maybe it has something to do with the version. I do not know. I am not really a proficient user in such an area so any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)